# Can UNIX socket fd property affect the behavior of select?

Tags: sockets, select

I have following simple program, one is server, one is client, source code is as following(I've deleted error handling to make code brief):

server.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0, connfd1 =0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    char sendBuff[1025];
    time_t ticks; 
    int one = 1;
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&one, sizeof(one));

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    listen(listenfd, 10);
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
    ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\n", ctime(&ticks));
    write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 
    close(connfd);
    close(listenfd);
    printf("existing...\n");
}
```

client.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    fd_set rset;
    fd_set wset;
    fd_set eset;
    struct timeval tv;
    int nready;
    int count;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345); 

    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr);
    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    count = -1;
    while(1){
        FD_ZERO(&rset);
        FD_ZERO(&eset);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &rset);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &eset);
        memset(&tv, 0, sizeof(struct timeval)); 
        tv.tv_sec = 1;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
        sleep(1);
        count ++;
        printf("loopcount is %d\n", count);

        nready = select(sockfd + 1, &rset, 0, &eset, &tv);      
        if(nready < 0){
            printf("error in select, exit\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(nready == 0){
            printf("nothing ready, continue...\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset)){
            printf("socket read\n");
            n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff) - 1);
            if(n < 0){
              printf("read error\n");
            }else if(n == 0){
                 printf("zero bytes, we assume it is EOF\n");
            }else{
                 printf("read n = %d\n", n);
                 recvBuff[n] = 0;
                 printf("%s\n",recvBuff);
            }
        }
        if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &eset)){
            printf("socket exception\n");
        }
     }
     close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

So the code is very simple, server just waits for the first client, then it writes current time to it, then server will close all the FDs and exit.
In client, it first connects to server, then it will infinitely select this sockfd for read and exception.
The run result in my test machine is:

```
./client 9.21.63.207
loopcount is 0
socket read
read n = 25
Fri Jun 13 02:50:53 2014

loopcount is 1
socket read
zero bytes, we assume it is EOF
loopcount is 2
socket read
zero bytes, we assume it is EOF
loopcount is 3
socket read
zero bytes, we assume it is EOF
```

We can see that after server exits, the select in client side still reports nReady > 0, and sockfd can be read, although read return 0 since we have reached EOF. I think this makes sense. But when I embed this simple code to a larger system(It is our company's product, about 1.5M lines of code), after server exits, the select in client side will report nReady ==0, please note, it just returns 0, not -1, meaning that no error occurs here....

Since our project is very complex, I don't know why this simple code behaves differently when it is embed in a larger system instead of a standalone application. My guess is that may be our project set some global socket options that affects the behavior of select? I don't know, does anyone have a clue why? Thanks.

Comment: This is just a wild shot in the dark, but does your real server (i.e. the one in the 1.5M-lines-of-code project) create any child processes? If so, then your problem could be that one or more of those child processes have automatically inherited a copy of the server's file descriptor for its socket, and that is why the socket stays open even after the original server process exited. If that's the problem, you could avoid it in Windows by calling SetHandleInformation((HANDLE)fd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) on the socket, or in Unix/Posix-land by closing the socket inside the child process.

Comment: @Jeremy: You are genius! It is indeed the cause as you stated, there is a child process that doesn't close the fd, thanks very much!